# Top Navigation Bar script

Tags: script, stackoverflow, design

The following script for Tampermonkey (Chrome) or Greasemonkey (Firefox) will add the links which have been moved to the new sidebar design to the top of the page. Make sure you also [hide the sidebar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369107/3626537) to get the correct look.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I made it so that a few things can be customized, namely showing or hiding the Jobs link, and changing the colors to your liking.

---

#### Script to copy to Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Overflow custom top navbar
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Make Stack Overflow Design Great Again #MSODGA :)
// @author       https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42632/phrancis
// @include      http*://*.stackoverflow.com*
// @include      http*://stackoverflow.com*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    'use strict';

    const stackOverflowOrange = '#F48024';

    // User of script can set these preferences to modify the script's behavior
    const userPreferences = {
        // Change to true to hide the "Jobs" Stack Overflow Careers link
        hideJobsLink: false,

        // Set your own colors for the links here.
        // Make sure to use valid CSS colors like "#f48024" or "black"
        linkColor: 'black',
        linkHoverColor: stackOverflowOrange,
        linkClickColor: stackOverflowOrange
    };

    // It is recommended to not change anything below this comment
    // unless you know JavaScript, as it can break the functionality
    const links = [
        { name: 'Home', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' },
        { name: 'Questions', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions' },
        { name: 'Tags', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/tags' },
        { name: 'Users', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/users' }
    ];

    if (!userPreferences.hideJobsLink) {
        links.push({ name: 'Jobs', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab' });
    }

    // Set styles
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent =
        `#navbar-list {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    li.navbar-list-item {
      float: left;
    }
    li.navbar-list-item > a {
      color: ${userPreferences.linkColor};
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .navbar-link {
      color: ${userPreferences.linkColor};
    }
    .navbar-link:hover {
      color: ${userPreferences.linkHoverColor};
    }
    .navbar-link:focus {
      color: ${userPreferences.linkClickColor};
    }`;
    document.body.appendChild(style);

    // Create links
    const navbarContainer = document.createElement('div');
    navbarContainer.id = 'navbar-container';

    const navbarList = document.createElement('ul');
    navbarList.id = 'navbar-list';
    navbarContainer.append(navbarList);

    for (const item of links) {
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.className = 'navbar-list-item';

        const link = document.createElement('a');
        [link.className, link.href, link.textContent] = ['navbar-link', item.url, item.name];

        listItem.append(link);
        navbarList.append(listItem);
    }

    document.getElementById('content').prepend(navbarContainer);
})();
```

Comment: Small note: this doesn't work on meta, where clicking questions, etc, takes you back to the main page. Nice script otherwise!

Answer (score 2):

A modified version of the above code which works also on other network sites and not only on stackoverflow.com:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Overflow custom top navbar
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Make Stack Overflow Design Great Again #MSODGA :)
// @author       modified from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42632/phrancis
// @include      https://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include      https://*serverfault.com/*
// @include      https://*superuser.com/*
// @include      https://*askubuntu.com/*
// @include      https://*mathoverflow.net/*
// @include      https://*.stackexchange.com/*

// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
    'use strict';

    const stackOverflowOrange = '#F48024';

    // User of script can set these preferences to modify the script's behavior
    const userPreferences = {
        // Change to true to hide the "Jobs" Stack Overflow Careers link
        hideJobsLink: false,

        // Set your own colors for the links here.
        // Make sure to use valid CSS colors like "#f48024" or "black"
        linkColor: 'black',
        linkHoverColor: stackOverflowOrange,
        linkClickColor: stackOverflowOrange
    };

    // It is recommended to not change anything below this comment
    // unless you know JavaScript, as it can break the functionality
    var url = window.location.origin;
    const links = [
        { name: 'Home', url: url },
        { name: 'Questions', url: url+'/questions' },
        { name: 'Tags', url: url+'/tags' },
        { name: 'Users', url: url+'/users' }
    ];

    if (!userPreferences.hideJobsLink) {
        links.push({ name: 'Jobs', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab' });
    }

    // Set styles
    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.textContent =
        `#navbar-list {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }
    li.navbar-list-item {
      float: left;
    }
    li.navbar-list-item > a {
      color: ${userPreferences.linkColor};
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1.4em;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .navbar-link {
      color: ${userPreferences.linkColor};
    }
    .navbar-link:hover {
      color: ${userPreferences.linkHoverColor};
    }
    .navbar-link:focus {
      color: ${userPreferences.linkClickColor};
    }`;
    document.body.appendChild(style);

    // Create links
    const navbarContainer = document.createElement('div');
    navbarContainer.id = 'navbar-container';

    const navbarList = document.createElement('ul');
    navbarList.id = 'navbar-list';
    navbarContainer.append(navbarList);

    for (const item of links) {
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.className = 'navbar-list-item';

        const link = document.createElement('a');
        [link.className, link.href, link.textContent] = ['navbar-link', item.url, item.name];

        listItem.append(link);
        navbarList.append(listItem);
    }

    document.getElementById('content').prepend(navbarContainer);
})();
```